# the question about the closed nest

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

For each $\xi>0$, $S+\xi B$ is a closed bounded set,

where $S$ is a closed bounded subset of $int ~dom f$, $B$ is the unit ball,

$domf$ denotes the effective domain of the proper convex function $f$.

My question is  that why the nest of sets

$$ ( S+\xi B ) \cap  (int~ dom f)^{C}$$

is empty.

Comment: Recently, i have the above question, proposed by another person. Thus, I just give my proof in two places

Answer (score -1):

Proof.

If not, there exists $x_0 \in \cap_{\xi>0} H_{\xi}$,
where $H_{\xi}= (S+\xi B) ~\cap Q$ with $Q =( int~ domf)^{c} $.

Notice that $S$ is in the interior of domf. 
For any $y\in S$, there exist $\alpha_{y}>0$ such that
$$B(y,0.5\alpha_{y})\subset B(y,\alpha_{y})\subset int ~ dom f.$$
It follows that $$S\subset\cup_{\alpha_{y}>0} B(y,0.5\alpha_{y}).$$
Since $S$ is a closed bounded set of $R^{n}$, $S$ is compact.
Thus, $$S\subset \cup_{i=1}^{m} B(y_i,\beta_i),$$
where $\beta_i = 0.5 \alpha_{y_{i}}$ and $m$ is an positive integer.
Thus, there exist $\xi_0= \min \{\beta_i\mid i= 1,2,\cdots,m\}$ such that

$$S +\xi_0 B\subset \ int ~dom f .$$

Together with the above inclusion, $x_0 \in H_{\xi_0}$ implies that 
$$x_0 \in int ~dom f.$$
However, $x_0 \in H_{\xi_0} \subset Q$ which shows us a contradiction.

Comment: Recently, i have the above question, proposed by another person. Thus, I just give my proof in two places.